# Cannot view CSS File in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: css

I am unable to open the CSS files in my project through Visual studio. The file details are intact and is not affected.If I try to open it, the error message that is displayed is
The operation could not be completed. Unspecified Error. I use VS 2008

Answer (score 0):

I would start by verifying the file exists and can be opened (notepad++ or the likes). IF the file exists: try removing the file from the solution/project, save the solution, close the IDE, open IDE and add the file again.